Children's book from the late 90's with Ostrich drawn on every page
Read a children's book (3 to 6 years target audience) to my children about a (possibly) animal protagonist that has an afternoon's adventure in  a city.  On every page of the story, there is a Ostrich in the background.  Ostrich is not the theme of the book, or important to the story line, it's just drawn there.  Actually took a couple readings to realize the Ostrich was in every scene - but not in a "Where's Waldo" kind of way.
I would like to get a copy for my granddaughter (aged 2 years), which would be about the right age group (as I recall).
Searching the Internet for any combination of "Ostrich, children, book, illustrated" does not produce correct answers.  Again, the Ostrich is not in the title of the book, or even a central character.  It's just on every page.

The Escape of Marvin the Ape by Caralyn and Mark Buehner perhaps?


When Marvin the Ape makes a break from the zoo, he heads straight downtown to the heart of the action, where he discovers everything the big city has to offer. Dining at the finest restaurants, strolling through museums, commuting with the crowds and rooting for the local baseball team, Marvin fits right in with the natives. And he may never leave!"

A search for book hidden ostrich on each page led to this Facebook post.


Do you know there's a hidden ostrich on every page in THE ESCAPE OF MARVIN THE APE? Some of them are a little tricky.


Awesome!!!  Have over 50 children's books (wife is a pre-school teacher), but not that one.  As I recall, Escape of Marvin the Ape was one of the better ones.
Also thanks for migrating to Literature.

@jumbosgrimps: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the check mark. But thank you!

Really hard to find the ostrich in the top right picture. I think I found it, but I'm not totally sure.

Ditto. I left a comment on the Facebook post.

@Barmar And confirmed to be between the right-hand officer and the passenger. You can just barely make out his head and eye.

It's almost Escher-esque the way it appears there.

Once you see the ostrich, you can't unsee it!
